# difference between different two way of resizing a image using cv2, without keeping aspect ratio same

Tags: python, opencv

I am resizing my image to a particular size (512,512) .
One of the way is resizing the image not caring about aspect ratio.
Below are the two method for doing it

1.

```
resize_scale_x,resize_scale_y=(512/float(img_width),512/float(img_height))

img_resized = cv2.resize(img,None, fx = resize_scale_x, fy = resize_scale_y,interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
```

2. 

```
img = cv2.resize(img, dsize=(512,512),interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
```

are both method same, and equivalent ?

Comment: I would expect #2 to always give an exactly 512x512 pixel result.  In #1, the floating-point math being done could conceivably have a rounding error, resulting in a dimension of 511 or 513 pixels.

Comment: Will there be any other issue beside the dimension size ?

Comment: in the documentation, [link](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html?highlight=resize#resize)                                                                
  'cv2.resize(src, dsize[, dst[, fx[, fy[, interpolation]]]]) → dst'
                                                                                                                                      it seem behind he scene it does the same thing,  if dsize , here(512,512)  and dst not given       fx=(doule) dsize.width/sorse.cols , fy =double) dsize.height/src.rows